# Make a QDialog stay above application window with Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint set on Mac OS

Tags: macos, qt, qt4

I have a Qt application which (upon users request) should stay above other windows. I achieved this by setting Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint in the windowsFlags of my application.

But whenever I open a system-modal QDialog derived dialog like QFileDialog, this Dialog stays underneath my own application. I could now try to find all dialogs and construct them with Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint, but

- this is tedious due to the large number of dialogs,
- prone to error, if I miss one,
- and for some dialogs, this does not work at all, e.g., QColorDialog::getColor() does not offer a interface where I could pass a WindowFlag.

Environment is Mac OS X Lion, Qt 4.8.1.

Comment: That's the problem - the dialog started with exec() will be underneath my application (unless created itself with Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint, which is not an option stated for the reasons above).

Comment: Even u open dialog with exec(), it is still underneath of your application? Hmmm.... exec() makes QDialog modal dialog and it should be top of your application.

Comment: may be you can try "QDialog.raise()" also.

Comment: raise() will not help in case of the QColorDialog, which is created and executed from a class static method. Event though raise() is an interesting idea, I could try to write an application event filter which raises the dialog upon creation (what event I will filter for remains to be found out)

Comment: That the opened dialog remains under my application is a (well-known) bug in Qt Window handling sind Qt 4.3 I think. A fix for that bug seems to exists but was never published (if I read the blogs of the Qt developers correctly)